# Does ReceiveAsync Method in 'Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client' Consumes Internet?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-iot-hub

I am using Azure SDKs on IoT devices. One of the methods I rely on is

```
public Task<Message> ReceiveAsync();
```

which appears in this namespace

```
namespace Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client
```

Under this class

```
public sealed class DeviceClient : IDisposable
```

I am calling this method continuously within a while loop as follows

```
        while (true)
        {
            var receivedMessage = await _deviceClient.ReceiveAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)).ConfigureAwait(false);

            if (receivedMessage != null)
            {
              //Do staff
            }
        }
```

My question is: does this consume internet quotas even though the `receivedMessage` always shows null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Digging through the source, you'll find three handlers:

- `HttpTransportHandler`
- `MqttTransportHandler`
- `AmqpTransportHandler`

Which one is used, depends on your configuration. The HTTP one will issue a GET request per `ReceiveAsync()`, costing network traffic.

The MQTT handler operates on TCP or WebSockets, where keepalive traffic may be involved. But given this communication is bidirectional, most traffic that occurs involves actual messages being delivered. `ReceiveAsync()` simply gets the first message from the internal receive queue, if any, or waits for one to arrive, it doesn't poll.

The AMPQ handler also operates on a message queue, and I can't quite figure out whether a `ReceiveAsync()` will ultimately incur network traffic.

Comment: Perfect, how to easily measure each how much it consumes?